# get relative paths to files in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a folder structure as follows:

```
.
└── FolderA
    ├── a.cpp
    ├── b.cpp
    ├── c.cpp
    ├── FolderB
    │   ├── trial.cpp
    │   └── trial1.cpp
    └── FolderC
        └── srcFolder
            └── anothercppfile.cpp
```

I wanted to store the names of all `.cpp` files which are present in `FolderA` in an array. I have to ensure that I preserve the relative paths of the files which are present in folders inside `FolderA`.

I can use:

```
require 'find'
cpp_file_paths = []
Find.find('path/to/search') do |path|
  cpp_file_paths << path if path =~ /.*\.cpp$/
end
```

But I do not get the relative paths. I am unsure on how to proceed. The final array must be:

```
["a.cpp",
 "b.cpp",
 "c.cpp",
 "/FolderB/trial.cpp",
 "/FolderB/trial1.cpp",
 "/FolderC/srcFolder/anothercppfile.cpp"]
```

Comment: Your question is still not much clear.. Could you draw a FS Tree and tell us the exact output? That will help us to help you confidently ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`Dir.glob`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-glob):

Starting with Ruby 2.5 there's a `base` argument:

```
cpp_file_paths = Dir.glob('**/*.cpp', base: 'FolderA')
#=> ["a.cpp", "b.cpp", "c.cpp", "FolderB/trial.cpp", "FolderB/trial1.cpp", "FolderC/srcFolder/anothercppfile.cpp"]
```

For older Rubies, you can [`chdir`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Dir.html#method-c-chdir) into the base directory:

```
Dir.chdir('FolderA') do
  cpp_file_paths = Dir.glob('**/*.cpp') #=> ["a.cpp", "b.cpp", "c.cpp", "FolderB/trial.cpp", "FolderB/trial1.cpp", "FolderC/srcFolder/anothercppfile.cpp"]
end
```

Note that the paths are relative, i.e. they don't start with a `/`. Passing a block to `chdir` ensures that the current directory is restored afterwards (thanks Arup Rakshit).

Comment: Nice answer! You can *pass* the block with `::chdir` method.